# Enable auto-indent in python-mode (python.el) in Emacs 24?

Tags: emacs, elisp, python-mode

I've recently declared emacs bankruptcy and in rebuilding my config switched from the old `python-mode.el` to the built-in `python.el`.

One thing that's I'm missing is the old behaviour of auto-indenting to the correct level when hitting `RET`. Is there any way to re-enable this?

Answer (score 4):

In upcoming Emacs 24.4 auto-indendation is enabled by default thanks to `electric-indent-mode`.  Since Emacs 24.4 has been in feature-freeze for quite some time now, there should be no major breaking bugs left, so you could already make a switch.

Comment: Indeed, and please note that in order to enable it by default, `electric-indent-mode` has seen some improvements: the version in 24.3 is unusable with python.el, whereas the version in 24.4 should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```lisp
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'my-python-hook)

(defun my-python-hook ()
  (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent))
```

Comment: I combined your answer with lunaryorn's as follows, `(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'electric-indent-mode)`.

Comment: this change added indent when I hit <RET> but now it indents with several tabs (5 or 6) for new .py files. How can I set it to 4 white spances?